# How to solve Ruler Control flickering

Tags: c#, flicker, doublebuffered

I'm using this [Ruler control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4369/Ruler-Control) in my project.

The mouse tracking line that is drawn into the ruler flickers when the mouse moves. I've tried to add this line inside its constructor:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

but nothing changes. How can I solve this flickering issue?

Comment: Strange issue ? Tried the control but it works fine for me.Try to run [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxnt1153cv12vg6/Ruler%20Test.zip),reply if the problem persists.

Comment: Have you set the mousetrack to true?

Comment: Yes, almost all properties are at defaults.